# how to inject d3 dependency?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

I am new to angularjs ,i inject d3 in main.js as follow:

```
      function (angular) {
            'use strict';

        angular.module('main', ['ngFileUpload', 'ngCookies', 'ui.router', 'd3'])
         .constant('_', window._);

      })(window.angular);
```

but i get an error:

```
       Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] 
       Failed to instantiate module main due to:
           Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module d3 due to:
         Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'd3' is not available! You either              misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure              that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Comment: is d3 is your angular directive  ? or just lib js file ?

Comment: just add lib to your index d3 is not angular directive or module you can't add this way but if you have js added you can use d3 in your controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using normal d3 library you dont inject angular dependencies.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

You can use d3.js angular directives or d3 "wrappers" angular directives, i recommend you:

- [nvd3](https://github.com/angularjs-nvd3-directives/angularjs-nvd3-directives)
- [c3-angular-directive](https://github.com/jettro/c3-angular-directive)

Comment: Then you dont need inject 'd3' in your angular.module. You just need import d3.min.js script in your index.html and you can call d3.js functions everywhere.

Comment: @IvanCoronado, I've been injecting it and that service also adds the script above to the DOM, and returns a promise with the raw D3 object on script load.  Won't that guarantee that D3 is ready for use were if you depend on the global D3 object it might not be pulled down yet?