# AngularJS, cannot add modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

So I am quite new to `AngularJS` and I can't seem to add additional module lets say for example `d3` for graph.

So My code for adding new modules is

```
  (function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('infographicsModule', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngTouch', 'ngSanitize', 'ngMessages', 'ngAria', 'ngResource', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'toastr']);
})();
```

But if I try to add `d3` as an additional module it throws an error

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module infographicsModule due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module d3 due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'd3' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Any suggestions? If you require more code, I can post it.

Comment: Are you trying to use a third party wrapper, or just d3.js on its own?

Comment: well I am trying to use d3.js that is compatible with angular to build graphs, I have installed d3 like this `bower install d3 --save` did that help?

Comment: I have been doing things like directives with d3, but I just don't understand how can you inject it as a module

Comment: you maybe find answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32269050/how-to-inject-d3-dependency

Comment: ah, so thats the thing, I don't need to load it... okay, its already there.

Comment: Yep, the answer @Kelvin linked is right - D3 is not an Angular module, it's just standard JavaScript. You don't need to include it in your Angular app's dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's happen cause D3 isn't an angular module.

You can try do this with the following link: https://github.com/WealthBar/angular-d3

Or you can encapsulate in a service or factory and call from this.

Comment: Yea, I was creating directives and it was totally fine. I was able to make them to work. But when I am trying to use and `angular` module like `nvd3-directives`  it throws me an error